# Can I force a second "Network Login" (captive portal) prompt from GNOME Shell?

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, authentication, gnome-shell, connectivity

I am running GNOME Shell and I have installed [network-manager-connectivity-debian](https://packages.debian.org/testing/network-manager-config-connectivity-debian). When I first connect to a WiFi hotspot a "Network Login" window opens (a chromeless browser), and I can enter my credentials to get internet access.

(This applies to hotspots at multiple locations and serviced by different ISPs. Some are paid, some are free-for-30-minutes. I don't know which ones do or don't use [WISPr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISPr).)

However, sometimes the "Network Login" window disappears suddenly, so I can't interact with the captive portal. (For example, to see how much credit I have left and/or top up my credit.) And sometimes I close it accidently :P

How can I force the "Network Login" window to reappear? (whether or not I still have internet access)

*I already have a handful of numerous workarounds for these situations. I specifically want to know how to get the "Network Login" window back.*

Comment: Pay attention about moving the goalposts. While I understand the concept of refining a question, the question can devolve into something else entirely.  It may come to a point where it is more useful opening another question. What is your true question here, bypassing the 30-minutes limit?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I think the problem is that my first phrasing assumed a solution which was misleading - additionally, I am not trying to bypass anything, or look for workarounds - I have updated the question again to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

For a generic method of logging in via a shell, use a text browser like `lynx`; it will open the page and allows you to login or click the image to unlock the Internet access.

When dealing with portals that talk the Wispr protocol, try to investigate if you can find a Wispr compliant script that will be able to automate the login.

One utility that is Wispr aware in the Unix world is Firefox, which obviously does not work in a shell. If in difficulties, try to open it to unlock the Internet access.

Comment: I think my first attempt wasn't clear so I've overhauled my question (thanks for the feedback) -- I don't know if your answer stands as-is? I'm specifically talk about the GNOME Shell prompt (I don't know if it's WISPr aware)

Comment: The shell prompt is not supposed *per se* to be HTTP/wispr aware; you still can install and use lynx